# Use of rotating in two different form

Tags: adjectives

There are two senteces below which i wrote. In these sentences, i used rotating in two diffrent form. I am sure that second one is correct.I wrote the first sentence based on the phrase “ a 360 degree rotating knife “. Please correct me if the first one is wrong .

> 1) The knife is 360 degree rotating (adjective)
>
> 2) The knife is rotating by 360 degree( present continuous tense)

Answer (score 1):

If there is such a thing as a “360 degree rotating knife”, then your first sentence is grammatical. It would be an acceptable answer to the question “What kind of knife is that?”

Your second sentence is not grammatical*. If you want to describe what the knife is doing, which is going around in a full circle, you just say “rotating 360 degrees” - without the “by”. You would say “rotated by” if you were describing how the position of the knife changed- “the knife was rotated by 360 degrees”- but this doesn’t work with the present progressive tense.

*EDIT: maybe it is grammatical and sounds ok to some, but it doesn’t sound natural to me as an American English speaker.

Comment: Thanks a lot . That knife is used for plastic crusher :).

Comment: @languagelearner you’re welcome, and I also made an edit. I’m not 100% sure “by” is always wrong in the present progressive tense (but it sounds unnatural to me).

Comment: In any case you do need to use the plural “degrees” for any number besides 1.